# How to test a rest service returning boolean in response using TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I have a rest service written using Spring Boot as below:

```
@RestController
class MyBankingController{

@GetMapping("/getCards")
public SomePOJO getCards(){}

@GetMapping("/cardPresent")
public boolean isCardPresent(@RequestParam(value = "username") String 
username){

 //calls service layer to return primitive true or false
}
}
```

Below is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyBankingApplication.class, webEnvironment = 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyBankingControllerIT {

private MyBankingController myBankingController;
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
private static final String BASE_URL = "/company/cards";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
String username = "1234";

@Autowired
private MyBankingService myBankingService;

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    myBankingController = new MyBankingController(myBankingService);

    restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
}

@Test
public void testIsCardPresent() throws JSONException {
    String url = BASE_URL+"cardPresent?username="+username;

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);

    ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            createURLWithPort(url),
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, Boolean.class);

    assertTrue(response.getBody());
}

private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
    return "http://localhost:" + port + uri;
}
}
```

I am unable to test this boolean return type. I have tried a couple of different things but it doesn't work. I am getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.Boolean out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.Boolean out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Please note that the above code is just a customized version of the actual code and that at the moment it is not possible to change the return type or the controller. 
Could you be able to tell me how to test this?

Comment: I guess it's a `String` already, try parsing it, should work

Comment: Instead of the assert, I tried System.out.println(response.getBody()); / System.out.println(response.getBody().toString()); but it gives the same error. Do you mean something else?

Comment: `ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(createURLWithPort(url), HttpMethod.GET, entity,String.class);` - please try this way

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I am no more getting that error now, but it seems the test is not calling the controller at all. I am getting a {"timestamp":1547205713809,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/company/cards/cardPresent?username=1234"}. I have checked the path, it is correct. Can you see why my test is not working?

Comment: It worked finally, and you were right, String instead of Boolean did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with further development!

Answer (score 0):

Change the response type to String as sketched below, and test for "true" "false" and it should work:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            createURLWithPort(url),
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```